# File download not working show wired character wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I Want to add download file in the site, but when I click on download It shows weird character. I dont know what the error is. I have added type application/octet-stream in my code. I think there is problem of permission but I have also set permission in c-panel :

Here is my file download code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["file"])){
                     $file = urldecode($_REQUEST["file"]); 
                      $filepath =  ABSPATH.'/wp-content/themes/xorisk/document_upload/'.$file;
                     if(file_exists($filepath)) { 

                        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filepath).'"');
                        header("Content-Type: mime/type");
                        header('Expires: 0');
                        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

                        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                        header('Pragma: public');   
                        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));

                        readfile($filepath);
                        exit;
```

Comment: Remove `header("Content-Type: mime/type");`, you already have `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');`

Comment: I have removed mime type but not working

Comment: I've just tested your script locally and I don't get an error or corruption with file, the download box launches and saves my test file correctly (text file).

Comment: yes it works in the local. but not working in server. I have made a directory in theme document_upload all the images and document I have upload there.

Comment: This script is work in php but not work in wordpress

Comment: Where are you using this script? in custom template ???, its working for me in custom template

Comment: Yes I am using this in custom template and upload file is in custom folder that is in under themefolder. How you add folder path in for get the file?

Comment: Where you upload the file?